# How to do this cycle in Django-templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I make a cycle like this in django

```
for i in arr:
    for j in arr[i]:
        pass
```

I tried this:

```
{% for i in arr %}
     {% for j in arr[i] %}

     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what is the format of `arr`? You no need to do `arr[i]`. Only `i` is enough.

Comment: That code wouldn't be valid in Python either. That's not how for loops work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following

```
{% for i in arr %}
     {% for j in i %}

     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```